# How can I mark skipped test case as fail in TestNG?

Tags: testing, sbt, testng

I am using `sbt test` to run `TestNG` test cases:

I get a testing result like this

```
===============================================
xxxx-test
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================

[info] Passed: Total 2, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 2
[success] Total time: 8 s, completed May 11, 2019 11:44:59 AM
```

The configuration failure is caused by an error in `@BeforeClass` phase.

The problem is my CI treat this result as passed.

How can I mark the whole test failed if any of my test cases skipped?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to modify the test result to fail via IMethodListener or ITestListener?

Comment: I have tried. But it sees I can only print something out... and cannot modify the result. Can you provide some detail examples?

Comment: Refer to <https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/testNG+-+changing+test+results+dynamically>